How to delete a Sheety project?
I have two projects of the same name in my Sheety dashboard. Both projects are linked to the same google sheet, which was created by someone else. I would like to delete both projects and create a new one using my own google sheet.
The title sounds too cheeky to believe, right!? So please find an image of my dilemma below and thank you for your help!


change edit at the end of URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit#gid=1193287107

to copy:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../copy

and make yourself a copy that you are owner of


Thank you, player0. But now, how can I verify who the owner is? Both old and newly copied version have the gid=0.

@HappyUmo see picture from answer how to verify ownership of spreadsheet. GID is ID of individual sheet within spreadsheet. first sheet of every spreadsheet is always gid=0

Projects are deleted in the 'Settings' tab. Deleting a project will make it's API unavailable immediately and cannot be undone.

